# Using node.js on AWS ec2 t1.micro?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2

I'm attempting the "Hello World" node.js script but I'm running into a hiccup....I'm executing the program but it's not connecting to my localhost:8080 because right after I execute the program when I go to my browser, I'm getting a Chrome "Oops Google cannot find" page. I am running from a AWS t1.micro ec2 instance in Cygwin on Windows so I'm not sure if its a CPU problem but I'm puzzled as to what's happening and I don't want to move forward without understanding why.

```
  var http = require("http"); //How we require modules

  http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200); //Status code in header
    response.write("Hello World!"); //Response body
    response.end(); // close the connection
  }).listen(8080);

 console.log('Listening on port 8080...');
```

Comment: Are you opening the Chrome on the ec2 instance ?

Answer (score 1):

Does your chrome also run on the same t1.micro?
Otherwise you need to use the IP-adress/domain name of the instance.

Make sure your Security Group allow port 8080 to be reached from your local machine.